# Orchard query projection not refreshing

Tags: c#, caching, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I have query projection with a custom filter that shows certain items. I also have a widget that allows entering a code. When the code is activated the whole page is refreshed (location.refresh(true)) and the custom filter should show different items from the query.

However, in my case neither the ApplyFilter method of the filter, nor the Display method of the widget shape is called again. The breakpoints are not hit.

It seems to be some kind of internal caching of Orchard, but I don't know how to force reloading these items manually. I am using Orchard 1.8.1.

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:
I switched to posting to an MVC Controller instead of a Web API with client refresh and it triggered the query filter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Tokens to pass your parameters for your projection?

Comment: Nope. I cannot see how to pass them via tokens. My parameter is an internal service, that is taking care of the validation of the given code and the ApplyFilter method formulates the query predicate with regards to that context.

Comment: I thought you might have a custom part, which you could add to your projection filter, using Manage Bindings. This is what I meant by using a token as a query predicate.